# Can I use cleveref to format a reference to an external entity?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

## Question

How can I cite a figure, section, or equation from an external document, but reference it using the same formatting as I use in my document via the `cleveref` package, regardless of how `cleveref` reference style was set up?

## Example

Suppose I wish to refer to an equation (say, their ninth equation) in some other document. Suppose `cleveref` was set up so that `\Cref{eqn:myEqn}` in the text below resolved to something looking like `Equation~(1)`. In this case, I *could* simply use `Equation~(9)` to refer to the external equation, as done below.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

My equation is:
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:myEqn}
    f(x) = a x^2 + bx + c \text{.}
\end{equation}

My \Cref{eqn:myEqn} is equivalent to Equation~(9) of Smith et al. (2018). 

\end{document}
```

The problem is that if `cleveref` was later set up differently so that `\Cref{eqn:myEqn}` resolved to `Eqn.~1`, or `(1)`, or `Equation~1` (etc.), then anywhere I hard-coded `Equation~(9)` would need to be changed to match the new reference style.

Is there a macro in `cleveref` that can do this for me? I imagine I'd need to tell it what kind of reference it was (equation, figure, section, etc.) and what number or letter it should use to refer to it. If there was, perhaps it could be used like the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

My equation is:
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:myEqn}
    f(x) = a x^2 + bx + c \text{.}
\end{equation}

My \Cref{eqn:myEqn} is equivalent to \CrefFormatExternal[eqn]{9} of Smith et al. (2018). 

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `cleveref` documentation does not say anything about this. Are both files using `cleveref`? Of course, using number as label is not really useful. Your example is not compilable, anyway

Comment: The other document is a published manuscript, so I don't have access to it other than the PDF it was published in. I'm not hoping to somehow link two files using `cleveref`. I know I want to cite an equation in an external document, and I know what number the other document refers to that equation by.

Comment: Off-topic: You have asked some questions and some of them has answers, but you did not accept them. Please consider to go through your list of questions and accept the answers that are most valuable to you in order to show appreciation of the work done by users to help you -- anything other is exploitation of them

Answer (score 1):

My possible solution stores the current value of the counter (equation), then sets the counter (equation) to the 2nd argument value decreased by one, uses `\refstepcounter` and an automatically generated label. This is referenced by checking whether `r@X` is defined or not. `X` is the autogenerated label name. Of course, a weakness of this approach is, that every time the macro `\CrefFormatExternal` macro is called for the same value, it will generate such a label.

The starred version suppresses hyperlinks, the `\crefFormatExternal` is available as well.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\makeatletter

\newif\if@hyperrefpackageloaded

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
    \@hyperrefpackageloadedtrue
  }{}
}    

\newcounter{tmpcntr}
\newcounter{helpcntr}


\NewDocumentCommand{\CrefFormatExternal}{sO{equation}m}{%
  \setcounter{tmpcntr}{\value{#2}}%
  \stepcounter{helpcntr}%
  \setcounter{#2}{\numexpr#3-1}%
  \refstepcounter{#2}\label{cleverrefexternalref:\number\value{helpcntr}}%
  \@ifundefined{r@cleverrefexternalref:\number\value{helpcntr}}{%
  }{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      \Cref*{cleverrefexternalref:\number\value{helpcntr}}%
    }{%
      \Cref{cleverrefexternalref:\number\value{helpcntr}}%
    }%
  }%
  \setcounter{#2}{\value{tmpcntr}}%
}




\NewDocumentCommand{\crefFormatExternal}{sO{equation}m}{%
  \setcounter{tmpcntr}{\value{#2}}%
  \stepcounter{helpcntr}%
  \setcounter{#2}{\numexpr#3-1}%
  \refstepcounter{#2}\label{cleverrefexternalref:\number\value{helpcntr}}%
  \@ifundefined{r@cleverrefexternalref:\number\value{helpcntr}}{%
  }{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      \cref*{cleverrefexternalref:\number\value{helpcntr}}%
    }{%
      \cref{cleverrefexternalref:\number\value{helpcntr}}%
    }%
  }%
  \setcounter{#2}{\value{tmpcntr}}%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

My equation is:
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:myEqn}
    f(x) = a x^{2} + bx + c \text{.} 
\end{equation}

My \Cref{eqn:myEqn} is equivalent to \CrefFormatExternal*{9} of Smith et al. (2018). 


\begin{equation} \label{eqn:otherEqn}
    x_{1/2} =  \dfrac{ - b\pm \sqrt{ b^{2} - 4 ac}}{2a}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where does the hyperlink link to in the non-starred version?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use cleveref's internal commands to format a reference without any counters involved. The commands of the form `cref@<type>@format`, where `<type>` is the counter name (such as `equation`, `section`, or `figure`), seem to do what we want.

For example, `cref@figure@format{foo}{}{}` produces "fig. foo", or whatever is produced by the user-defined `\crefformat` for figures. Note:

- The two empty arguments are normally used to mark the beginning and end of the hyperlinked part of the reference (see documentation of `\crefformat`), but I assume no hyperlink is desired in this case.
- Because this internal macro has `@` in the name, we can't use it in a document except [after `\makeatletter`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/170009).

The following example defines a helper macro, `\crefcustom`, which invokes the internal command. `\Crefcustom` is the capitalized version.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand {\crefcustom}[2]{\csname cref@#1@format\endcsname{#2}{}{}}
\newcommand {\Crefcustom}[2]{\csname Cref@#1@format\endcsname{#2}{}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

My equation is:
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:myEqn}
    f(x) = a x^2 + bx + c.
\end{equation}

My \cref{eqn:myEqn} is equivalent to \crefcustom{equation}{9} of Smith et al. (2018). 

\end{document}
```